# How two make two lines of a table lie left and right?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can I make two line of a table not align, one `tr` is left, another is right, using `position:relative` or `position:absolute` and `margin`? But it also align.

### How can I make two `tr` not align?

I want this:

[image]

What I want this is:
I have a html:

```
<table>
  <tr colspan="2"><td>top</td><tr>
  <tr><td>left 1 2 3</td><td>right</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want hide the 'left 1 2 3' slowly as a animate, then the width of 'right' becomes 100%
but the effect I need is when left td hide, the whole td move left, first text 'left' disappear, then 1, then 2,3, then the whole td hide.

I have tried this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">          </script>
    <style>
    body{margin:0px}
    </style>
    <script>
        function hid() {
            $("#d1").animate({ "margin-left": "-102px" });
        }
    </script>
  <table id="d1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr >
      <td style="position: relative; width: 100px;         height:100px;border: 1px solid #0050D0;background: #96E555; cursor: pointer">
          123
       </td>
       <td>
           abc
       </td>        
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onClick="hid()">
```

This looks like what I want, but there is only one tr and it is move the whole table but not the tr.

Comment: Huh? Can you sketch it?

Comment: A `<tr>` is not aligned left or right, they are below each other. Or do you mean a `<td>`? They will automatically be next to each other.

Comment: i have added my detail above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8FUg/)?

```
<table style='width:100%;'>
<tr>
 <td style='text-align:right;'>RIGHT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style='text-align:left;'>LEFT</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, the best way to do this is with two floated  elements, as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8FUg/1/)

```
<div style='border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:44px;'>
<div style='float:right;width:80px;border:1px solid black;height:20px;'></div>    
<div style='clear:both;'></div>        
<div style='float:left;width:80px;border:1px solid black;height:20px;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added my detail above

Comment: I've updated the answer, you're best using divs as this is not what tables are meant for